# Need to wchar_t array to be global and built at runtime

Tags: c++

I am building this array at runtime, with hardwired values as a test.

Now I need the array to be globally declared at the top, and re-sized at runtime, and also filled with data pulled from a text file, not hardwired words as you see here:

```
wchar_t x1[] = L"Welcome";
wchar_t p1[8] = {7, x1[0], x1[1], x1[2], x1[3], x1[4], x1[5], x1[6]};
wchar_t x2[] = L"xTestx";
wchar_t p2[7] = {6, x2[0], x2[1], x2[2], x2[3], x2[4], x2[5]};
wchar_t * daFactors[2] = { p1, p2 };
long long ndaFactors = 2;
```

To clarify, the goal is to have this up top for global declaration:

```
wchar_t * daFactors;
long long ndaFactors;
```

I tried using `malloc(ndaFactors * sizeof(wchar_t))` in various forms and can't seem to get the `*`'s and `**`'s correct.  I also can't seem to add entries to an array if they are `wchar_t` themselves.

This is getting me closer - error msg of "cannot convert wchar_t** to wchar_t*":

```
    ndaFactors = 2;
    daFactors = new wchar_t * [ndaFactors]();
```

I'm asking for syntax assistance in achieving the goal as stated. These "words" will be in the thousands - get loaded when the program starts up - it is a multi-threaded service using this "data pool" for search items. It gets fed files - searching for the all these terms. All the search functions are written, I am simply porting them. You can imagine the simple loops they are running through `daFactors` comparing "single" characters and what not. They are all working out of the box.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `std::vector<wchar_t*>`.

Comment: What do you mean by *”do not want to use a vector for this”*? You should give a specific reason why.

Comment: Not looking to use a vector.  Existing code is getting ported and the functions all use structures like this - arrays of "size-first" strings.

Comment: You can still put an array of size-first strings in a `std::vector`. Just pass it to your functions as `daFactors.data()`.

Comment: @szlamany this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Please do not edit your question to post a solution. Either upvote and accept the answer that helped you, or post your own answer. I have reverted that edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

daFactors is a static array of pointers to arrays of wchar_t and it will always be the same size you gave it when allocating (you should also use `new` instead of `malloc` in c++). To change it's size in runtime, you would have to deallocate, copy and allocate again every time.

Fortunately, c++ has structures that would allow you to do the thing you want. The closest thing to a "dynamic size array" would be vector, as everything will be handled by you by the library. You can also use other things like linked lists, but that would not be an array.

Edit: based on your edited question, you need to change the type to `wchar_t ** daFactors;` in your declaration. It siginifies this is a pointer to (array) of pointers, hence two *

Comment: It's only being built once - it just needs to get data from a source.  It will be fixed.

Comment: This is not working for me - getting an error cannot convert wchar_t** to wchar_t* - I posted code snippet I just tried in the OP.  How would I use NEW??

Comment: @szlamany well then I misunderstood. If the size of the array doesn't need to change during the runtime then you only need to allocate the thing once at the start. In your snippet you need change the type to `wchar_t ** daFactors;`

Comment: @MartinYakuza No I misunderstood, the strings are created at runtime :)

Comment: The number will vary each time the program boots up - it's a service.  These "search words" number in the thousands - and get loaded once.  I'm going to look into just getting a pool of memory and using pointers - that seems like the actual low level way to achieve this.

Comment: @szlamany so if you the size of daFactors are supposed to change during the runtime, then using a vector or linked list is the best idea.

Comment: This is 100% all about speed - I cannot take a speed hit.  I already went down the path of a vector of wchar_t's and that did work.  I pulled it out after reading less efficient "read" time from a vector over an array.  I need to see my own benchmark testing of these search functions to make sure I don't follow suggestions that aren't taking this use case into account.  I need to get more details to add to this post I believe.

Comment: @szlamany I'm not sure if vector actually slows you down by much, but if you want to use "normal array", then you can allocate an array larger than you need and then use only a part of that array. That's assuming you know more or less how big this array will need to be during runtime. And it will take a bit more space some of the time, obviously.

Comment: Thank you - it worked as you stated - and I will post the code up top that worked for me - thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can fully automate your process at compile time.
Avoiding the need of global variables completely.
The length prefixed data can be generated from an expression like this :

```
static constexpr size_prefix_wstring_t x1{L"Welcome"};
```

Resulting in this (compile time generated) data

```
x1:
  .long 7 # 0x7
  .long 87 # 0x57
  .long 101 # 0x65
  .long 108 # 0x6c
  .long 99 # 0x63
  .long 111 # 0x6f
  .long 109 # 0x6d
  .long 101 # 0x65
```

What you need for this is a small constexpr (compile time) helper class like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
struct size_prefix_wstring_t
{
    constexpr size_prefix_wstring_t(const wchar_t(&wstring)[N])
    {
        static_assert(N < (sizeof(wchar_t) * 8ul));
        m_size_prefixed_string[0] = N-1;
        for(std::size_t n=0, n1 = 1; n < (N-1); ++n, ++n1)
        {
            m_size_prefixed_string[n1] = wstring[n];
        }
    }

    wchar_t* data() const noexcept
    {
        return m_size_prefixed_string.data();
    }

    constexpr std::wstring_view sv() const
    {
        return std::wstring_view{&m_size_prefixed_string[1],N-1};
    }
    
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept
    {
        return N-1;
    }

private:
    std::array<wchar_t,N> m_size_prefixed_string{};
};

static constexpr size_prefix_wstring_t x1{L"Welcome"};

int main()
{
    std::wcout << x1.sv();
}
```

Live demo here :

https://godbolt.org/z/Ke8qzsGd5

When you need these strings in more translation units move the constexpr code to a header file and inline it. Also the constexpr
string needs to become inline `inline constexpr size_prefix_wstring_t x1{"Welcome"};`

Comment: Thank you - that was a lot of effort you just went though.  I'm not looking to change the method in use here - I'm asking for syntax assistance in achieving the goal as stated.  These "words" will be in the thousands - get loaded when the program starts up - it is a multi-threaded service using this "data pool" for search items.  It gets fed files - searching for the all these terms.  All the search functions are written, I am simply porting them.  You can imagine the simple loops they are running through daFactors comparing "single" characters and what not. They are all working out of the box

Comment: No problem, and it wasn't much effort, just a few minutes. From your example I gathered everything was known at compile time, which it is clearly not :)

Comment: And you might still use it for your testcode where you do have test strings ;)